# how to reuse the xpr file in Mule 4

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mulesoft, mule4

In my case, I'm doing a **migration from Mule 3 to Mule 4**.

This flow, which includes **transformers** like DOM to XML, XML to DOM, and an **expression component**, needs to be migrated.

In **Mule 4**, I want to **reuse the xrp file**.

My flow for XML payload transform uses an XPR file by the expression component in Mule 3.

```
<flow name="rate-dtostepFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/dtostep" allowedMethods="POST" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <mulexml:xml-to-dom-transformer returnClass="org.dom4j.Document" doc:name="XML to DOM"/>
        <set-variable variableName="domPayload" value="#[payload]" doc:name="set domPayload "/>
        <expression-component file="xpr/responseStubCannasure.xpr" doc:name="Expression"/>
        <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer doc:name="DOM to XML"/>
</flow>
```

Input XML: https://github.com/Manikandan99/rate-dtostep/blob/master/request.xml

Output XML:  https://github.com/Manikandan99/rate-dtostep/blob/master/response.xml

my MULE 3 application : https://github.com/Manikandan99/rate-dtostep/tree/master/rate-dtostep

ResponseStubcannsure xpr file:

```
import org.dom4j.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("");

dtoCoverageStepsNodes = flowVars.domPayload.selectNodes("//DTOCoverage[@Status=\'Active\']/DTOSteps");
for (Node node : dtoCoverageStepsNodes){
    //logger.info("inside: detach");
    node.detach();
}

dtoCoverageNodes = flowVars.domPayload.selectNodes("//DTOCoverage[@Status=\'Active\']");
int i = 500;
for (Node node : dtoCoverageNodes){

    //node.detach();
    //logger.info("inside: assign prem");
    node.addAttribute("FullTermAmt", Integer.toString(i));

    node.addElement("DTOSteps");

    stepNode = node.selectSingleNode("DTOSteps");
    stepNode.addElement("DTOStep")
        .addAttribute("Order","1")
        .addAttribute("Name","Final Premium")
        .addAttribute("Desc","Final Premium Desc")
        .addAttribute("Operation","=")
        .addAttribute("Factor",Integer.toString(i))
        .addAttribute("Value",Integer.toString(i));

    i+=1;
}
```

The xpr file transform the xml payload in the following ways:

- updated the value of the DTOStep node.
- The attribute value of DTOStep is autoincremented from 500 each time.

Please assist me.

Comment: And as I explained previously inputs and outputs should be in the question, not just linked.

Comment: Hi Aled, In my view codey_08 transformed the input xml based on updating the value of DTOStep using that XPR file..

Answer (score 2):

You need to migrate the complete flow to Mule 4. The file responseStubCannasure.xpr is just a script in MEL (Mule 3 expression language). The extension is irrelevant, it could have been anything. MEL is very similar to Java so you could reuse the logic by encapsulating it into a Java class. You will need to add to the Java code the conversion to DOM4J from the input XML because Mule 4 doesn't support it. Probably is slightly easier to migrate the MEL script to a Groovy script because the basic syntax is very similar and both support scripts. Migrating to Java is just taking the additional steps of encapsulating the script into a method of a class and defining explicitly the types for variables.

Alternatively you could just delete the last 4 operations of the flow and replace them with a DataWeave transformation. Using a recursive function to navigate the keys and value recursively, using a condition to check if we are in the element DTOCoverage, with attribute Status == "Active" and then replace the nested element with the DTOSteps/DTOStep combination. Which is what your script does.

Example:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
var startingValue=500
fun transformSteps(x, index)=
    x filterObject ($$ as String != "DTOSteps") ++
    {
         DTOSteps: DTOStep @(Order:1, Factor: index + startingValue, Value: index + startingValue, Name:"Final Premiun", Operation:"=", Desc: "Final Premium Desc"): null 
    }

fun transformCoverage(x, index)=
    {
        val: x match {
            case is Object -> x mapObject 
                if ($$ as String == "DTOCoverage" and $$.@Status == "Active")
                    { 
                        DTOCoverage @(( $$.@ - "FullTermAmt" ), FullTermAmt: $$$ + startingValue): 
                            transformSteps($, index)
                    }
                else 
                    (($$): transformCoverage($, index+1)) 
            else -> $
        },
        index: index
    }
---
transformCoverage(payload,1).val
```

This solution doesn't completely resolve the Value and Factor (why two attributes with the same value?) sequential increase. You may need to do an additional transformation, or use Groovy or Java code to renumber them.

Comment: Aled, you're right. Could you please update the answer with encapsulating the logic in a Java class?

Comment: I added an example DataWeave script that resolves most of the problem. I'll leave the Java implementation to you. The answer is there, pointing you to the work that needs to be done.

Comment: Hi Aled, It's a close call. You did an awesome work. But In your Dataweave code, the attribute values for DTOCoverage are missing. Could you please update the code?

Comment: Aled, myself also worked on codey_08 xpr.its lit complex to transform in Dataweave code,but let encapsulating the logic in java code is easy I think so....

Comment: @codey_08 updated the script to copy the attributes. Only the expression `@(( $$.@ ))` needed to be added to DTOCoverage.

Comment: @ManiKandan I mostly did implement it in a few lines of DataWeave but YMMV. Probably it is slightly easier to convert the MEL script into a Groovy script, since both allow scripts and no type declaration for variables. Just adding the DOM4J code to convert an input XML into DOM4J nodes to the beginning might be enough.

Comment: Hi Aled,You did fantastic work. The attribute values for DTOCoverage are shown.However, the child node under the DTOCoverage is missing and how to update the FullTermAmt attribute values of DTOCoverage by "$$+startingValue" (500, 501...) Could you please update the code?

Comment: I missed that one, however you should be able to figure a missing attribute. I updated the answer anyway.

Comment: The other child nodes, like DTOLimit and DTODeductible, are missing from DTOCoverage while updating values of DTOSteps. Please update the code.

Comment: That is because you didn't define that transformation with enough details in your question. Anyway I updated the script. Also I noticed that FullTermAmt could also be duplicated and removed the duplicate.

Comment: @ Aled,You did excellent work. But there is an issue with the attribute value of Factor, Value in DTOStep and FullTermAmt in DTOCoverage. It shows 0.00. Could you please check it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241578/discussion-between-aled-and-codey-08).

Comment: @Aled, Now the attribute values are shown, but they miss the match for each iteration. If the FullTermAmt is 500, then the value of the DTOStep attribute, like factor and value, is also 500 for the same iteration. The attribute value of Factor, Value in DTOStep and FullTermAmt in DTOCoverage is not auto-incrementing. Could you please check it?

Comment: Hello, Aled. You mentioned that converting a MEL script to a Groovy script is a bit easier. I'm not familiar with Groovy script conversion. Could you kindly clarify it by codey_08 case?

Comment: Well, you can try to just execute the MEL script as a Groovy script and see what happens. You still need to add the DOM4J conversion to the script. Learning Groovy may be needed. If you are more familiar with Java try that path. If you are not a developer, better get one to help.

Comment: @aled. Thank you for clarifying that. If a jar file is required to use DOM4J.